# Calculate the time elapsed between events

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with temperature value recorded every 15 seconds. I want to calculate the time spend under a specific temperature value of 100.

Input

```
  ID  Temperature               Datetime
0  A          102  24/09/2017 7:00:00 AM
1  A          100  24/09/2017 7:00:15 AM
2  A           99  24/09/2017 7:00:30 AM
3  A           98  24/09/2017 7:00:45 AM
4  A          100  24/09/2017 7:01:00 AM
5  A           99  24/09/2017 7:01:15 AM
6  A           98  24/09/2017 7:01:30 AM
7  A          100  24/09/2017 7:01:45 AM
```

Output I am expecting:

```
ID             Hour_start               Hour_end  Duration
 A  24/09/2017 7:00:30 AM  24/09/2017 7:01:00 AM        30
 A  24/09/2017 7:01:15 AM  24/09/2017 7:01:45 AM        30
```

I can do this is parts, but need help.

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? If you show us what you tried, we can go from there. For more tips, like how to write a good title, check out [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

It seems that the question is asking for the start, end, and duration of consecutive intervals less than 100.

It seems that there are multiple IDs, not just ID A, so I created the code to work even when there are multiple IDs.

```
cond = df['Temperature'].lt(100)
grp = cond.ne(cond.groupby(df['ID']).shift()).cumsum()
out = (
    df[cond]
    .assign(end=df.groupby('ID')['Datetime'].shift(-1))
    .groupby(['ID', grp])
    .agg(
        Hour_start=('Datetime', 'first'),
        Hour_end=('end', 'last'),
        Duration=('Datetime', 'size'),
    )
    .droplevel(1)
    .reset_index()
    .assign(Duration=lambda x: x['Duration'].mul(15))
)
```

out

```
    ID  Hour_start              Hour_end                Duration
0   A   24/09/2017 7:00:30 AM   24/09/2017 7:01:00 AM   30
1   A   24/09/2017 7:01:15 AM   24/09/2017 7:01:45 AM   30
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'Temperature': [102, 100, 99, 98, 100, 99, 98, 100], 'Datetime': ['24/09/2017 7:00:00 AM', '24/09/2017 7:00:15 AM', '24/09/2017 7:00:30 AM', '24/09/2017 7:00:45 AM', '24/09/2017 7:01:00 AM', '24/09/2017 7:01:15 AM', '24/09/2017 7:01:30 AM', '24/09/2017 7:01:45 AM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```